# write "ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4" once for the whole script

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When exporting my database structure there is this `ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4` after every table creation. Do you have to write it for every table? Or is there a way to write it once for every table like (pseudo SQL)

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`;
USE `mydb`;
SET (ENGINE, `INNODB`);
SET (DEFAULT CHARSET, `UTF8MB4`);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it relatively easily by following these steps:

- 1) Take a dump of your database - for the sake of this example, I've used the MySQL `sakila` sample database [`"designed to represent a DVD rental store"`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-history.html). The command I used was:

  > mysqldump -u root -p sakila > sakila.sql

  You will then be asked for the password for the user that you are using - in this case I used `root` - this is **not** best practice!

Your dumpfile will contain many sections (2 examples shown) like the following (16 for the Sakila schema - one for each table in your database/schema):

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `actor`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `actor` (
  `actor_id` smallint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`actor_id`),
  KEY `idx_actor_last_name` (`last_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

and

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `category`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `category_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

- 2) The key lines in these sections are at the ends of the table definitions:

> ```
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=201 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

and

> ```
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
> ```

- 3) use your editor of choice to change `utf8` to `utf8mb4`. Or, if you're on Linux, you can use the [`sed` utility](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/):

> ```
> sed 's/utf8/utf8mb4/g' sakila.sql > sakila.sql.bis // the "g" is for "global"
> ```

- 4) Check your output file (belt and braces!) using your editor.

- 5) Drop your Sakila schema using your `mysql` prompt or from MySQL Workbench (or your tool of choice):

> ```
> DROP SCHEMA sakila;  -- "DROP DATABASE" does the same thing
> ```

- 6) Recreate an empty Sakila schema.

> ```
> CREATE SCHEMA sakila;  -- ditto "CREATE DATABASE"
> ```

- 7) Having verified sakila.sql.bis, rename it sakila.sql overwriting the old file.

- 8) Load your modified SQL file, again using `mysqldump` (in reverse so to speak - note the change of `>` to `<` - output to input).

> ```
> mysqldump -u root -p sakila < sakila.sql
> ```

Your final step is to [set the default character set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513812/470530) to `utf8mb4` in `my.cnf/my.ini`.

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

So now, all your tables will be `UTF8MB4` and any future tables will be created with the same character set. You can, as mentioned in the last link, also use different collations per table and/or per field, but that's not part of the question - an internet search should be sufficient to deal with this requirement should you need it.

Answer (score 2):

2 different techniques are needed:

```
SET default_storage_engine = InnoDB;
CREATE DATABASE foo DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
USE foo;

CREATE TABLE ....
```